# Wrong Image Loads when loading images in listview

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-listview, android-asynctask

I've seen a couple of questions like this, but I seem to be having a slightly different problem. So I thought I would ask someone on here.

I have a custom listview with a textview and an imageview. I am loading images using an async task and then setting the images to the imageview in my post execute method. My images are loading fine, but some images are replaced by other images. But after all the images are finished loading each imageview has the proper image. I cant seem to figure out why I have this problem though.

Here are my adapter and async task classes. Any and all help would be appreciated.

**EDIT** I am now adding a tag(The tag is the text that goes into the imageviews respective textview) and in my post execute I am checking if the tag is equal to the text from the textview. I am still having the same problem as before.

Here is my Adapter class:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomList> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    LinkedList<CustomList> data = null;
    LinkedList<String> title_list = new LinkedList();

    LoadImage l;
    CustomList cl;
    ProgressBar pb;
    HashMap <String, Bitmap> bitmap = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();







    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, LinkedList<CustomList> data, LinkedList<Bitmap> bitmap_list) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.data = data;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View row = convertView;
        CustomListHolder holder = null;




        if(row == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new CustomListHolder();

            holder.text = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            holder.thumbnail = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            holder.pb = (ProgressBar)row.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

            row.setTag(R.id.id0, holder);


            cl = data.get(position);
            holder.text.setText(cl.title);
            holder.thumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
            holder.pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            row.setTag(R.id.id1,new String(cl.title));
            LoadImage li = new LoadImage(context, holder.thumbnail, cl.icon,cl.title, bitmap,holder.pb,row);
            li.execute(cl.icon);        

        }

        else{
            Log.e("Row not null","Inside");
            holder = (CustomListHolder)row.getTag(R.id.id0);
            //row.getK
            cl = data.get(position);        
            holder.text.setText(cl.title);
            holder.thumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
            holder.pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if((Bitmap) bitmap.get(cl.title) == null){
                row.setTag(R.id.id1,new String(cl.title));
              LoadImage li = new LoadImage(context, holder.thumbnail, cl.icon,cl.title, bitmap,holder.pb,row);
                li.execute(cl.icon); 


            }
            else {
                holder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) bitmap.get(cl.title));
                holder.pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }



        }   



        return row;


    }

    static class CustomListHolder
    {
        ImageView thumbnail;
        TextView text;
        ProgressBar pb;
    }


}
```

Here is my async task class :

public class LoadImage extends AsyncTask{

```
Context callingContext = null;
ImageView view;
String bits;
public  ProgressBar pb;
HashMap<String, Bitmap> bitmap; 
String url;
String text;
View row;



public LoadImage(Context c, ImageView view, String bits, String text, HashMap<String, Bitmap> bitmap, ProgressBar pb, View row){

    this.view = view;
    this.bits = bits; // url for image
    this.callingContext = c;
    this.bitmap = bitmap; //hashmap
    this.text = text;// title text
    this.pb = pb;
    this.row = row;

}



public Bitmap getBitmap(String data){

    Bitmap bitmap;
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
    bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Log.e("getBitmap",text);

    try {
        bitmap=null;
        InputStream is=new URL(data).openStream();
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, bmOptions);
        is.close();
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = 10;
        is = new URL(data).openStream();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, o2);

        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 60, 60, true);
        is.close();
        this.bitmap.put(text,bitmap);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e("Debug", ex.getMessage());
       return null;
    }

}


@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("do In Bg",text);
    Bitmap b = null;    

    if((Bitmap)bitmap.get(text) == null)
      b = getBitmap(bits);
    else 
      b =(Bitmap)bitmap.get(text);

        return b;  
}



@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(row.getTag(R.id.id1).equals(text)){
            view.setImageBitmap((Bitmap)bitmap.get(text));
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }




}
```

}

CustomList is a class with 2 Strings icon and title. icon is the url of the image and title is the text for the textview.

Comment: What does your xml look like? Do you have a temp image in the image view? Sounds like you do, and when the `asynctask` is done loading, you get the correct image.

Comment: Does it only happen when scrolling?

Comment: @BlaineOmega - I set my image to be equal to the android launcher while the image is loading. Once its done loading the launcher gets replaced by the image. I'm loading 2 different images lets say a and b about 10 times. In my listview I have the images alternating. Even after the image loads, sometimes b takes the position of a and vice versa.However after all the images are completely loaded the images are in their right position.

Comment: @Krylez - This happens while scrolling and while at its stationary position.

Comment: Okay, one more question; if you never scroll at all does it still occur?

Comment: @Krylez - It doesn't happen if I don't scroll.

Comment: Have you considered moving your `getBitmap()` method to the `doInBackground`?

Comment: @BlaineOmega - Would that make any difference ? I am calling my getBitmap method within my doInBackground anyway.

Comment: @NickChris Did u manage to rectify this issue ? Please share your solution , I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure @Krylez was going to tell you the same thing: In a ListView, your rows are recycled. This is what the covertView gives you and you do a row==null check. If your screen shows up 10 rows at a time, it probably has about 11 to 12 rows in memory. As you scroll and a row goes out of view, it is held in memory and given back to you with the old stuff for you to repopulate.

Say you have cell 1... You asked for bitmap 1. Then the user scrolls it out of view and it is recycled as bitmap 12. Now the bitmap 1 task completes and draws on it because the object references are still intact (never got destroyed). So you get this effect of wrong images showing up.

I used an easy fix on an iOS project: use object tags. Let me explain:

When you fire off a LoadImage task, tag your row with a unique ID you can identify the bitmap and its position-relationship with...

```
row.setTag(new Integer(ID_THAT_IDENTIFIES_ROW_AND_BITMAP_RELATIONSHIP))
```

When its time to do your onPostExecute() in your Async Task, check to see if this identifier has changed. If your current bitmap is no longer matching, don't do anything because there's probably another task waiting to populate it.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Since I'll be setting a tag twice for my row(once for the holder and once for the integer) how do I specify it to give me the integer value ?

Comment: Yes. There are a couple more things you can consider. When you're dealing with a recycled view (convertView is not null), consider calling the cancel() method on the old async task right before firing off a new one. If you don't do this, scrolling back and forth through a long list will consume unnecessary cpu time. 

An advanced but worthwhile improvement would be to look into using an LruCache: https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/gooio2012/103/

Comment: My bad, It seemed to work on the emulator, but not on the device. I've updated my code. I have update my code as well.

Comment: @NickChris Did u manage to rectify this issue ? Please share your solution  , I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion in this case is always create new row.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater(); 
row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
```

Don't need use Holder (although that seem good for smooth).
Try it.

Thanks.